# how to place "dd" tag side by side html

Tags: html

I want to place "Age" and "Gender" side by side. How to place it. How to place **dl** tag side by side. I tried using **display:flex**, **display:inline**, but still not working.

[image]

```css
dl {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
 
dl dt {
    background:#5f9be3;
    color:#fff;
    float:left; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    padding:5px;  
    width:100px; 
}
 
dl dd {
    margin:2px 0; 
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

```html
    <dl>          
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd>John Don</dd>
             
    <dt>Age: </dt>
    <dd>23</dd>
                 
    <dt>Gender: </dt>
    <dd>Male</dd>
                 
    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: can u provide me with illustration of what u want?

Comment: i have updated with a screenshot of how i want to place "Gender" and "Age" side by side but without border. And i want to achieve this using dd and dt  .. Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a collapsed row in a flex item to make a new row, as described in [this blog post](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/).

```css
dl {
    margin-bottom:50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 
dl dt {
    background:#5f9be3;
    color:#fff;
    float:left; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    padding:5px;  
    width:100px; 
}
 
dl dd {
    margin:2px 10px 0 0; 
    padding:5px 0;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<dl>          
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd>John Don</dd>

    <div class="break"></div> <!-- break -->

    <dt>Age: </dt>
    <dd>23</dd>
                 
    <dt>Gender: </dt>
    <dd>Male</dd>

    <div class="break"></div> <!-- break -->    

    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

I added padding to the `.break` elements to space out the rows, and a right margin of 10px on the `dl dd` CSS rule to add some space between the two items on the same row.